# Please refocus on the Title field if there is an error there when asking

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, asking-questions

Over on Cryptography, I was wrapping up their [recent election](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/election/3). When I got to the meta post announcement, it wasn't posting and I couldn't tell why:

[image: Why isn't this working?]

Turns out there was already a [2018 Community Moderator Election Results](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1021/2018-community-moderator-election-results) announcement I made in February. But I didn't see the error because the page didn't scroll back to the title:

[image: Oh. I wrote that already.]

I'm using macOS version 10.14.1 and Chrome version 71, but I happen to know it also happened in a previous version of Chrome before I updated. In the past, I'm pretty sure the page did refocus. It does on Enterprise for sure. In addition, on Enterprise there is a notice under the "Post Your Question" button in case the focus doesn't change:

[image: I done screwed up.]

On the plus side, the new error message on the Title box is clearly superior to the old popup that was liable to drift offscreen if you changed your window size:

[image: Hello there!]

At any rate, just refocusing to the Title if there is an error would make a big difference. (And I think the title errors should take priority over tag or body errors if I have those too.)

Answer (score 8):

This was apparently triggered by the move to inline "[Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/inputs#validation-states)" validation a few months back. The editor currently supports both inline and old-style pop-up validation messages, but the checks on submission responsible for scrolling (and displaying the message below the button) weren't updated to be aware of the newer styles... As a result, it would fail to find the old-style messages and just give up, leaving you staring at the button.

I've updated this logic to work with *both* sets of styles. If there's an error specific to an element, that element will be scrolled into view; if that doesn't happen for some reason (or you scroll away from it), the message below the button will be rendered as a reminder until the error is cleared.

[image: Message "Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the errors above." shown below "Post Your Question" button]

[image: animation of the scrolling that happens when validation fails]

Comment: The error message under the button needs a tad of white-space at the top, no? Or is that due to interference with one of your userscripts?

Comment: Not my scripts this time, @rene (good eye though - the *actual* page doesn't have a "populate template" link on it...). I guess it could stand to have a bit more space there, but I'm not overly concerned right at the moment.